# How to filter an array of objects based on specific objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dataset

I am trying to 'filter' this array of objects to only get the `newCases` and `date`. Moreover, I would like to convert this into a `DataSet` with x being the `date` and y being `newCases`.

```
"actualsTimeseries": [
{
"cases": 1,
"deaths": 0,
"positiveTests": null,
"negativeTests": null,
"contactTracers": null,
"hospitalBeds": {
"capacity": null,
"currentUsageTotal": null,
"currentUsageCovid": null
},
"icuBeds": {
"capacity": null,
"currentUsageTotal": null,
"currentUsageCovid": null
},
"newCases": null,
"newDeaths": null,
"vaccinesAdministeredDemographics": null,
"vaccinationsInitiatedDemographics": null,
"date": "2020-03-09"
},
{
"cases": 3,
"deaths": 0,
"positiveTests": null,
"negativeTests": null,
"contactTracers": null,
"hospitalBeds": {
"capacity": null,
"currentUsageTotal": null,
"currentUsageCovid": null
},
"icuBeds": {
"capacity": null,
"currentUsageTotal": null,
"currentUsageCovid": null
},
"newCases": 2,
"newDeaths": 0,
"vaccinesAdministeredDemographics": null,
"vaccinationsInitiatedDemographics": null,
"date": "2020-03-10"
},
{
"cases": 3,
"deaths": 0,
"positiveTests": null,
"negativeTests": null,
"contactTracers": null,
"hospitalBeds": {
"capacity": null,
"currentUsageTotal": null,
"currentUsageCovid": null
},
"icuBeds": {
"capacity": null,
"currentUsageTotal": null,
"currentUsageCovid": null
},
"newCases": 0,
"newDeaths": 0,
"vaccinesAdministeredDemographics": null,
"vaccinationsInitiatedDemographics": null,
"date": "2020-03-11"
},
...
}
```

I have attempted to do this, but need help on how to sort the dates.

```
const dataArray = actualsTimeseries.map((info) => info);

    const getPastCases = () =>
      Object.entries(dataArray).sort(([date1], [date2]) =>
        date1.localeCompare(date2)
      );

    const DataSet = (casesByDate) =>
      casesByDate.map(([dateString, cases]) => ({
        x: new Date(dateString),
        y: cases.newCases,
      }));

    const resData = DataSet(getPastCases());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Comment: Somewhat, but I need a way to match and sort the date property with `newCases` and convert it into a `DataSet`.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.